# Python Library installation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I have two questions regarding python libraries:

1. I would like to know if there is something like a "super" python library which lets me install ALL or at least all scientific useful python libraries, which I can install once and then I have all I need.
2. There is a number of annoying problems when installing different libraries (pythonpath, cant import because it is not installed BUT it is installed). Is there any good documentation about common installation errors and how to avoid them.
3. If there is no total solution I would be interested in numpy, scipy, matplotlib, PIL

Thanks a lot for the attention and help

Best

Z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Enthought Python Distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php)

Comment: I'm not aware of a freely available one that is as comprehensive as EPD. Depending on what you're planning to do though, adding the modules you're interested in to Movable Python (http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/movpy/) might be an option. There'd still be some configuration annoyances but once it's up and working, you'd effectively have your own "distribution"

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I use a MacbookPro. So the exact question would be: 

Is there a free (open source) super library that runs on a mac. 

But thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

In Windows enviroments, [pythonXY](http://www.pythonxy.com/) is what your are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Several options are listed at http://new.scipy.org/download.html#software-distributions-that-include-numpy-scipy

Comment: I wrote this page :) Glad it's proving useful.